# How to quickly get to the first compiler error message in terminal?

Tags: terminal, compiler-errors

I feel like this is a common question, but I couldn't find anything on it. Often times when I compile a program, I'll have a long list of compilation errors, and I have to scroll up in the terminal to find the first error. This is kind of tedious and sometimes I scroll past the first error without noticing. Is there a quicker way to navigate this?

Answer (score 1):

### Terminal-specific approach:

```
$ clear && make
```

Then use the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> to jump to the top. This shortcut may not be available for all consoles. It seems to work for gnome-terminal and agetty. It does not seem to work for xterm, but I would assume that such consoles can be configured to add a shortcut (e.g. for xterm see [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108408/how-to-scroll-to-the-bottom-or-to-the-beginning-of-a-terminal-session-in-xterm)).

### Compiler-specific approach:

Alternatively, you could use compiler mechanisms for limiting the number of errors to be shown. Both clang and gcc support `-Wfatal-errors` for exiting on the first error (not to be confused with `-Werror` which turns warnings into errors). From the gcc `man` page:

```
       -Wfatal-errors
           This option causes the compiler to abort compilation on the first
           error occurred rather than trying to keep going and printing
           further error messages.
```

Exiting on the first error might be unhelpful in some cases (i.e. when missing some header, there might be an error about a missing `;` before the error telling you which identifier is undefined).
For this reason, it might be more helpful to limit the number of errors. For gcc there is `-fmax-errors=n` (for clang `-ferror-limit=n`) for showing at most `n` errors. You could adjust it to a small number that allows you to see all errors at once without scrolling.

```
       -fmax-errors=n
           Limits the maximum number of error messages to n, at which
           point GCC bails out rather than attempting to continue
           processing the source code.  If n is 0 (the default), there is
           no limit on the number of error messages produced.  If
           -Wfatal-errors is also specified, then -Wfatal-errors takes
           precedence over this option.
```